# Python Selenium Could not select dependent second dropdown after selecting first dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape https://www.autotrader.com/model-information and get all combinations make-model of dropdown values (such as Audi-a4, Audi-a6, etc).

I can click and select the values from the first dropdown (car make dropdown) without a problem. But when I try to click and select the value in the second dropdown (model dropdown), TimeoutException error shows up.

[error like this][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLM5h.png

Looks like the second dropdown cannot be clicked thus the option values cannot be showed while using chromedriver. When I browse the website and click the first dropdown myself, the second dropdown become clickable immediately and all values show up in the dropdown.

I do not know how to fix this since the url, ID, XPATH, nothing change after choosing values of the first dropdown.

It may be something to do with anti-blocking. Maybe the website recognize I am a bot and block me from scraping.

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/opt/anaconda3/bin/chromedriver')   
 ### paste chromedriver path as executable_path here
driver.maximize_window()
url = "https://www.autotrader.com/model-information" 
driver.get(url)

makelist=[]
modellist=[]
#### First work with the drop down menus with car makes 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="makeCode"]').click()
make = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="makeCode"]/optgroup[@label="All Makes"]/option')
#### Loop through all makes in the drop down menus
for makeele in make:
    makelist.append(makeele.get_attribute('text'))
    makeele.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    #### Work with the drop down menus with car models of specific make
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ModelCode"]'))).click()
    model = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ModelCode"]/optgroup[2]/option')
    #### Loop through all models in the drop down menus
    for modelele in model:
        modellist.append(modelele.get_attribute('text'))
        modelele.click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: What is `makelist`? It is not defined

Comment: I don't get the same error, I get a stale element reference when I run your code. (with `makelist` and `modellist` commented out). Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your issue.

Comment: @vitaliis edited my code already

Comment: @C.Peck I think you get a stale element reference error if the website somehow block you (the site shows it is unavailable while scraping(

Comment: Oh, Ok, if that is the case hopefully someone who can see the content will be able to help.

Comment: @C.Peck Thanks. I have been constantly blocked by this website as well. That is another issue that I need to work on later on. :)

Comment: Divide your code into smaller parts for debugging. Without loops. You will less probably be banned then. Also, you do not click the car make. In irder to get models, click it. The reason (in 90%) why that field is not available is because site blocks it because it recognises you as a bot.

Comment: @vitaliis I thought makeele.click() do the clicking. I also try <driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='makeCode']").click()>
<driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='makeCode']").send_keys(str(makeele.text))> to click the car make. But I still have the same error.  Do you have any recommendations for not using loop? I don't really know how to go through so many makes and models without using a loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the site blocks this dropdown from enabling details. So the problem is not even your code, but the fact that you are opening the site as a robot.

I debugged it and I never had this field enabled (probably only once), even after a car make was selected. It just remains disabled

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.maximize_window()
url = "https://www.autotrader.com/model-information"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

makelist = []
modellist = []
#### First work with the drop down menus with car makes

make_dd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="makeCode"]')
model_dd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ModelCode"]')
makes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="makeCode"]/optgroup[@label="All Makes"]/option')
models = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ModelCode"]/optgroup[2]/option')

#### Loop through all makes in the drop down menus
# for i in range(len(makes)):
#     n = 1

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="makeCode"]')))
make_dd.click()


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="makeCode"]/optgroup[1]/option[{1}]')))
make = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="makeCode"]/optgroup[1]/option[1]')
make.click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ModelCode>optgroup[Label='All Models']")))
model_dd.click()
```

What this code does:

1. Clicks the first dropdown
2. Selects the first option (Acura)
3. Waits for model dropdown and tries to click it.
   I could developed it further if someone would find a workaround for bot detection.

Also note that I got rid of any time.sleep() and put explicit waits instead.

P.S. I suggest dividing big problems into a smaller ones and solve them one after one.

I did not want to answer first after seeing that I was blocked, but finally decided to add some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. I will think over your suggestion.

Comment: I can try later again. I think I was banned because I tried clicks in a loop and the site immediately detected it.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to work out this problem.

The reason why the second dropdown menu cannot be clicked is because the website detect I am a **scraper** and block me. My approach is to use a real chrome website instead of using a simulation.

```
## Generate changing userAgent to prevent block
cmd1  = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
cmd2 = ' --remote-debugging-port=9222'
subprocess.Popen([cmd1, cmd2])
time.sleep(3)
options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', '127.0.0.1:9222')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path='/opt/anaconda3/bin/chromedriver')    ### paste chromedriver path as executable_path here
driver.maximize_window()
url = "https://www.autotrader.com/model-information" 
driver.get(url)
```

Other parts of the code remain the same.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ not scrapper.